# Index suddenly out of range in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to implement an [algorithm to find all primes below a certain limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). However, when the limit reaches `46350` i suddenly get an `out of range` error message:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /tmpfs/gosandbox-433...fd004/prog.go:16 +0x1a8
```

Any help to point me to what is wrong here is appreciated (and were does this magic number `46350` come from?).

To reproduce drop the following code into [googles sandbox](http://play.golang.org/) and uncomment `limit++` (or use [this link](http://play.golang.org/p/vRCRCPRdp2)):

```
package main

func main() {
    limit := 46349
    //limit++
    sieved_numbers := make([]bool, limit)
    var j = 0
    var i = 2

    for ; i < limit; i++ {
        if !sieved_numbers[i] {
            for j = i * i; j < limit;j += i {
                sieved_numbers[j] = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because when `i == 46349`, `j = i * i` overflows and you're left with a negative number. The loop condition is still true, but it's outside the boundaries of the array, so you get a panic.

Add a `fmt.Println(i, j)` as the first statement in your nested loop, and run it on your local machine (it'll time out on the sandbox) and you'll see it happen.

Comment: Oh boi what a stupid mistake. Thanks!
Changing all variables to `unit64` solve the issue.

Comment: Rather than use uint64, you can `break` from the i for-loop when `i*i >= limit`. This makes the code faster too!

Answer (score 4):

`i*i = 2148229801` when `i==46349`. A signed 32 bit integer can only reach ~`2^31` (32 bits - 1 bit for the sign) before it becomes negative. Specifically, your variable would have taken on the value of `(2^32)/2 - (46349^2)` which is `-746153`.

If you'd like to perform this computation, try using an unsigned int or an int64.

```
package main

// import "fmt"

func main() {
    var limit uint
    limit = 46349
    limit++
    sieved_numbers := make([]bool, limit)
    var j uint = 0
    var i uint = 2

    for ; i < limit; i++ {
        if !sieved_numbers[i] {
            for j = i * i; j < limit; j += i {
                sieved_numbers[j] = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it on the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/9uuIifu-UY)

Answer (score 2):

`i * i` produces a number which is greater than the maxiumum size of a 32 bit signed integer.

You should use a larger data type for `j`.

Read about integers on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29)